# Storing HTML form templates in a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am allowing users to create custom forms with any number of inputs and elements of their choosing. I then want the user to be able to save that form as a template of sorts so that other users could use that template to create their own custom form just like it.

There could be hundreds of different post types, each one with different elements etc.

What might be the best way to accomplish this in PHP and MySQL?

I am thinking of just storing the html of the custom form once a user has created it in the database. And so if another user wants to use that template, I'd just retrieve that html from the database and present it to the new user.

Is this the best way to do this? Many sites do similar things (Wufoo, for example), it just seems a little weird to me to store raw html like that in a database.

Comment: Why can't you just store the the number and type of inputs with names/labels/default values etc?

Comment: That's an option, but there could be dozens of different variations of those things for each 'template' and storing and reading them from a db in an organized way so that another form could be constructed as a complete duplicate seems for more complicated than just one database entry that contains the entire html of the form. But I don't know for sure? That's whay I'm asking :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anytime you're thinking of storing HTML in a database you're *probably* on the wrong lines.

What if you want to make generalised structural changes to all forms? You'd suddenly have to go through all records and make that change.

Instead, think in terms of using the DB only to store the bare bones of what's necessary **to recreate the form later**.

Perhaps you'd have one DB table to store forms, another table with a one-to-many relationship to it that stores each field definition, and so on.

So your DB would store the number of inputs, their type, labels, validation requirements - whatever. Then you'd have a big script that would rifle through these and - voila - rebuild the form.

This approach:

- gives you greater control of the general HTML structure
- adheres more closely to the concept of normalising your DB data
- adheres to the concept of keeping separate your data and structure (i.e. HTML)
- cuts down the amount of data stored (no repeated tags, whitespace etc)

Answer (score 2):

IMO, best method would be to store the form data field in a data structure (e.g. JSON) and build your html from that. You could optionally cache the html as well for purpose of faster rendering if needed.

If implemented well, this has the advantage of keeping data about what your forms should contain in a consistent format, which means if you ever want to update the html rendering logic you would be able to have it update the html for all stored forms immediately (or simply clear their cached html, and next time that particular form is rendered, cache the new HTML), rather than trying to kludge together something that parses inconsistently saved HTML data and attempts to update them all.

Note this may slightly reduce the flexibility that your users get since you'll have to limit their options to a finite set of available things to add, but the benefits in long-term maintenance will generally greatly outweigh this downside.