# Submit Html Templates to Database

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a drag and drop module which is used to create html templates. I mean drag and drop html text, header, footer etc. I have many layouts like two column, three column etc. in which these html elements can be dropped. What I want is the following .

> To determine which element (header,footer,text etc.) is in the columns
>   in a 2 column or 3 column structure

Is there any way to save these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830620/storing-html-form-templates-in-a-database?rq=1). I am not deleting this because someone could find this in their search. Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27830674/8913606) to the question